# error: passing ‘const Vector<int>’ as ‘this’ argument of ... discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am trying to figure out SGI STL recently, and I write my own Vector, but I have trouble with a simple test code. when I tried to compile it, it complaint like this:

```
error: passing ‘const Vector<int>’ as ‘this’ argument of 
‘Vector<T,Alloc>::value_type* Vector<T, Alloc>::end() 
[with T = int; Alloc = __default_alloc_template<false, 0>; Vector<T, Alloc>::iterator = int*; Vector<T, Alloc>::value_type = int]’ 
discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
size_type size() const { return size_type(end() - begin()); }
```

I have looked up in the usage of const function, it says that if the code does not change any member in the class, then it can be a const function.

I really do not understand, the size() does not change any member in the Vector, just invokes two other functions.

I checked SGI_vector, and I think it is quite the same to my code.

What's wrong with it? Thank you!

```
int main(){
    Vector<int> v2;
    cout<<"sizeof(v2): "<<v2.size()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have write my own Vector like this:

```
template <class T, class Alloc = alloc>
class Vector {//primary template
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef value_type* iterator;
    typedef size_t  size_type;

protected:
    typedef simple_alloc<value_type,alloc> data_allocator;
    iterator start;
    iterator finish;
    iterator end_of_storage;

public:
    iterator begin(){return start;}
    iterator end()  { return finish; }
    size_type size() const { return size_type(end() - begin()); }
    Vector():start(0),finish(0), end_of_storage(0){}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size()` is a `const` member function. From this function, you can only call other `const` member functions. The calls to `begin()` and `end()` in `size()` are not allowed since `begin()` and `end()` are non-`const` member functions.

You can just use the member variables `start` and `finish` to implement `size()`.

```
size_type size() const { return size_type(finish - start); }
```

Comment: check [this site](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_vector.h), and search for the implementation of size(), I think the ```const-member function``` calls the ```non-const member functions```

Comment: That implementation of `std::vector` has `const` and non-`const` overloads of `begin()` and `end()`. The `const` version returns a `const_iterator` while the non-`const` version returns an `iterator`.